# Can "for cause" be employed in a context other than legal or contractual matters?

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering if "for cause" can be employed in a context other than legal or contractual matters. What I have in mind, is a journalistic context such as in:

> Violence is on the rise in Antwerp. For cause are regular disputes among drug dealers.

Is this correct word usage?

**EDIT**

In reality, the bit of text that I am editing is much longer. To maintain clarity, I really would like to have two sentences, where the second sentence explains the cause or reason. In a nutshell, I am looking for other ways to say "The reason is …"

Comment: Why the down-voting, if all I am doing is asking a simple question?

Comment: The cause is x.

Answer (score 1):

No, **for cause** is typically only used as a legal term in contracts, especially related to employment.

Some alternatives:

> Violence is on the rise in Antwerp because of regular disputes among drug dealers.

> Regular disputes among drug dealers are the cause of the rising violence in Antwerp.

> Regular disputes among drug dealers are causing the rising violence in Antwerp.

Comment: Violence is on the rise in Antwerp. It arises/springs from regular disputes among drug dealers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that "for cause" is not proper in the example sentence.

My alternative choice would be "due to":

> Violence is on the rise in Antwerp due to regular disputes among drug dealers.

Comment: You could make the second sentence "A major cause is regular disputes among drug dealers." (maybe 'between' instead of 'among').